# [[ $var -eq 0 ]] returns true even when the variable is unset, empty, or contains only spaces and tabs

Tags: bash, shell

This statement:

```
[[ $var -eq 0 ]]
```

returns true when `var=0`, when `var` is not defined, when `var=''` and when `var='    '` (only spaces and tabs), I instead want the statement to return true only when `var=0`.

How can I get this?

Comment: ...if your goal is making things you expect to be error conditions cause explicit failures, btw, [consider `set -u`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/112).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want `var` to be interpreted as a number (including trying to coerce non-numeric values into a reasonable numeric interpretation), use `=` instead to do a string comparison rather than a numeric one:

```
[[ $var = 0 ]]
```

Note that converting an empty string to 0 isn't the only coercion done when a non-numeric value is used in an arithmetic context. For an example of another one:

```
var1='var2'
var2=3
[[ $var1 -eq 3 ]] && echo "Strings can be coerced to indirect references"
```

Comment: Why not `==`?..

Comment: Ah ok, for conformance to the standard `POSIX`

Comment: Exactly. `[[` is extended behavior by nature, but using `=` even there avoids developing muscle memory that might lead one to use `==` with `[` where it's a nonportable extension several common implementations reject.